# Error in `/usr/bin/java': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: in JNI

Tags: java, c, post, java-native-interface, tomcat7

I am getting data packet via HTTP POST request using RESTful API.Then parsed this packet using JNI and it returns the result to java.
While it running, after several HTTP POST request tomcat server crashes and shows an error  `"Error in /usr/bin/java: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f40b40011d0"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer for this anyway.Its because of you are freeing the memory before allocating it.Thats the reason for my error.

> The free() function frees the memory space pointed  to  by  ptr, 
>   which    must  have  been  returned  by a previous call to malloc(),
>   calloc() or    realloc().  Otherwise, or if free(ptr) has already been
>   called  before,    undefined behavior occurs.  If ptr is NULL, no
>   operation is performed.